# Font size macro in tikz font style

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have a set of tikz styles I use for multiple `tikzpicture`s in my document. These styles are in `nodestyle.tex`. I can optionally modify the size in those styles by doing `\newcommand{\trnodesize}{1em}` before `\input{nodestyles}`. I want to do the same for the font size, but can't get it to work (see below).

document.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% For use in nodestyle.tex
\newlength{\mnodesize}

\begin{document}

% Default node styling.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\input{nodestyle}
\node [inner] at (0, 0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Smaller nodes (and text).
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\trnodesize}{1em}
% This currently has no effect:
\newcommand{\trnodefontsize}{\tiny}
\input{nodestyle}
\node [inner] at (0, 0) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

nodestyle.tex:

```
% Want a default value; most of the time 1.5em is ideal.
\providecommand{\trnodesize}{1.5em}
\setlength{\mnodesize}{\trnodesize}
% Again, usually \normalsize is fine.
\providecommand{\trnodefontsize}{\normalsize}

\tikzset{
  inner/.style = {
    align=center,
    inner sep=0pt,
    white,
    solid,
    fill=red,
    text centered,
    text width=\mnodesize,
    minimum height=\mnodesize,
    font=\sffamily,
    % Doesn't work:
    % font=\trnodefontsize\sffamily,
  },
}
% So the next \newcommand{\trnodesize}{...} and
% \newcommand{\trnodefontsize}{...} will work.
\let\trnodesize\undefined
\let\trnodefontsize\undefined
```

Uncommenting the `font=\trnodefontsize\sffamily` line results in undefined control sequences at both `\node [inner] ...` lines. Using e.g. `font=\small\sffamily` works just fine, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. How can I fix this?

I imagine there will be *much* better ways of achieving the kind of functionality I'm going for, and will happily accept alternatives as answers - but I'd still like to know why the above does not work.

Comment: Why do you use `\let\trnodefontsize\undefined`? This causes the error messages, in my point of view

Comment: Because every time I use `\input{nodestyle}`, I want the default values to take effect *unless* I have defined new ones immediately prior to `input`.  Oh, but yes, I see now why this causes the error messages!

Comment: Sam, the redefinitions occur all in a group (in `tikzpicture`), they are safe outside. It's no need to use `\input{...}` every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view the big error is to use `\input{...}` with `tikzpicture` with this setup.

It's alright to load the general `nodestyle.tex` in the preamble and doing the `\renewcommand` definitions for  `\trnodesize` and `\trnodefontsize` inside `tikzpicture`. Such redefinitions occur within a group and do **not** change outside settings.

The setting of the `\trnodesize` does not lead to change of `mnodesize` unless `\setlength` is used. Since lenghts are used in registers, a length change within a group does not leak outside of the group!

`\providecommand` settings are ignored if the command is defined already.

```
\providecommand{\trnodesize}{1.5em} 
\setlength{\mnodesize}{\trnodesize}
% Again, usually \normalsize is fine.
\providecommand{\trnodefontsize}{\normalsize}

\tikzset{
  inner/.style = {
    align=center,
    inner sep=0pt,
    white,
    solid,
    fill=red,
    text centered,
    text width=\mnodesize,
    minimum height=\mnodesize,
    font=\sffamily,
    % Doesn't work:
    font={\trnodefontsize\ttfamily},
  },
}
% So the next \newcommand{\trnodesize}{...} and
% \newcommand{\trnodefontsize}{...} will work.
%\let\trnodesize\undefined
%\let\trnodefontsize\undefined
```

In order to make the redefinitions effective, use a `\setupmytikz` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% For use in nodestyle.tex
\newlength{\mnodesize}

\input{nodestyle}

\newcommand{\setupmytikz}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\trnodesize}{#1}%
  \setlength{\mnodesize}{\trnodesize}%
  \renewcommand{\trnodefontsize}{#2}%
}


\begin{document}


% Default node styling.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner] at (0, 0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Smaller nodes (and text).
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setupmytikz{1em}{\tiny}
  \node [inner] at (0, 0) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [inner] at (0, 0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *"Such redefinitions occur within a group and do change outside settings."* - By this, do you mean that doing a `\renewcommand{\trnodesize}` inside a `tikzpicture` environment will affect the value of `\trnodesize` in any code which follows? If so, is there a way to force `\trnodesize` back to the default `1.5em` after `\end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, typo: **do not change**